# Java: Purpose of mapper / map in tutorial example

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

I am currently reading the Java tutorial from Oracle.

In the chapter on Lambda Expressions (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) I don't understand the purpose of the mapper parameter in approach 7/8 and the usage of the map method in approach 9 respectively.

approach 7:

```
public static void printPersonsWithPredicate(
    List<Person> roster, Predicate<Person> tester) {
    for (Person p : roster) {
        if (tester.test(p)) {
            p.printPerson();
        }
    }
}
```

approach 8:

```
public static <X, Y> void processElements(
    Iterable<X> source,
    Predicate<X> tester,
    Function <X, Y> mapper,
    Consumer<Y> block) {
    for (X p : source) {
        if (tester.test(p)) {
            Y data = mapper.apply(p);
            block.accept(data);
        }
    }
}
```

approach 9:

```
roster
    .stream()
    .filter(
        p -> p.getGender() == Person.Sex.MALE
            && p.getAge() >= 18
            && p.getAge() <= 25)
    .map(p -> p.getEmailAddress())
    .forEach(email -> System.out.println(email));
```

Couldn't this just be ommitted and the lambda expression `email -> System.out.println(email)` replaced by `p -> System.out.println(p.getEmailAddress())` (after adjusting the corresponding data types).

Does anyone have a hint or an idea why the map method / mapper parameters are introduced in these examples or sees a flaw with my considerations?

thank you
regards
Martin

Comment: `.map` takes something and transforms it to something else, in your case `Person` is transformed to a `String` (assuming `emailAddress` is a `String`)

Comment: In this specific example, sure. But what if you want to make a list of email addresses. You would need collect(Collectors.toList()). But without a mapper, it would create a List<Person>. So you need to transform persons into email addresses first.

Comment: Yes, in this example that would work perfectly fine. In more complex cases mapping makes the code a lot more readable. For example if you follow it up with a `filter()` call, like if you only want to print email addresses that end with `@gmail.com`.

Answer (score 2):

The mapper function on approach 8:

```
Function <X, Y> mapper
```

is a function that takes a reference type of `X` as input and returns another reference type of `Y` as output. if you look carefully within the body of the `if` statement on approach 8 it shows:

```
Y data = mapper.apply(p);
```

this is executing the behaviour that `mapper` is referecing and returning a result.

for the last approach you cannot do:

```
p -> System.out.println(p.getEmailAddress())
```

because at that time we have `Stream<String>` and not a `Stream<Person>`

However, if you're referring to omitting the call to `map` and replacing the `forEach` *behaviour parameterizatio*n with `p -> System.out.println(p.getEmailAddress())` then yes that would work also.

> Does anyone have a hint or an idea why the map method / mapper
>   parameters are introduced in these examples or sees a flaw with my
>   considerations?

The `map` method is introduced within this example because the author wanted to print the e-mail addresses of those members contained in the collection `roster` who are eligible for Selective Service as mentioned within the link you've posted. so in order to do that, we can either map a `Stream<Person>` to a `Stream<String>` or use the other approach you've suggested.

Comment: I think OP suggested omitting the call to `map()` AND replacing the `forEach()` with `p -> System.out.println(p.getEmailAddress())`

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Yes, in fact ommitting the call to map() and replaceing the forEach parameter was what I meant in the original question.